# Why is SVG subimage displayed improperly in chrome, unless viewport is made bigger than required

Tags: svg, rendering, viewport

I am rendering SVG image out of multiple subimages (visualising industrial installation).   And parts of those subimages are not rendered in chrome  when viewport is set to smallest possible extent ( other viewers like  one in IntelliJ do not have any prolbem with it ).  Image is assembled from  subimages along negative Y-Axis,and then rotated into viewport.  Viewport size is calculated to include all corner points of all the modules.

SVG  with display problems in chrome:
http://www.pribluda.de/test_svg/testRender_90.svg

( segments are cut on the left side )

Same SVG,   but with wiewport height increased is displayed properly:

http://www.pribluda.de/test_svg/testRender_x18.svg

And when rotated only 45 degrees:

http://www.pribluda.de/test_svg/testRender_45.svg

Images created with plain rectangles instead of actual  module pictures do not have this problem -  unfortunately I can not change those module images as they come from third party.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,   here comes the  answer.    As it turns out,   indivudual subimages  had no explicit width and height set.   Once  this problem was adressed,    everything started to work as intendet:

http://www.pribluda.de/test_svg/testRender.svg

It seems important for chrome rendering engine to have this information -  otherwise parts of the images may be optimised away.

Before:

```
  <g transform="matrix(0.0 1.0 -1.0 -0.0 0.0 -0.0) "
><g transform="matrix(1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 -225.0) "
  ><svg contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" zoomAndPan="magnify" modulenr="0" contentStyleType="text/css" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0"
    ><defs
```

After:

```
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(0.0 1.0 -1.0 -0.0 0.0 -0.0) "><g transform="matrix(1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 -225.0) "><svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" width="130" zoomAndPan="magnify" modulenr="0" contentStyleType="text/css" height="225" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.0">....
```